# Why are special characters ignored in search

Tags: discussion, search

Why doesn't the search engine of stackoverflow support searching for special characters?

I want to search for the meaning of `class<?>` in java, however the `<?>` part gets ignored.
This way I can't effectively search for what I want to know.

Comment: check out [stackse](http://stackse.com)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simply enclose what you're trying to search for in quotes:

```
"class<?>"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22class%3C%3F%3E%22

Since you said you're using Java, you could also add the `[java]` tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22class%3C%3F%3E%22+%5Bjava%5D

Comment: The [`hascode`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) selector may be usefull

Comment: @brasofilo: Mmmm... I can't get that to work? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hascode%3A%22class%3C%3F%3E%22+%5Bjava%5D I also tried just `code:` to no avail; http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22class%3C%3F%3E%22+%5Bjava%5D

Comment: Never used it much, but also had difficulties on my first trial...  Not on the desktop now to test further.

Comment: `hascode` is a boolean property. So `hascode:1` will return results that have a code block.

Answer (score 3):

Try [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com), it's specifically designed for this!

Comment: symbolhound.com sadly appears to be discontinued.

Comment: nooooooooooooooooooooooo