# Unwanted search results on 'locale'

Tags: support, search

A search for [[delphi] locale](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[delphi]+locale) or [[delphi] localization](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[delphi]+localization) turns up tons of results containing *local* and its variants, with some needles on *localization* in the haystack.

That's not what I use a search engine for ;-)

Can something be done about this? It looks like some incomplete index/dictionary/thesaurus is in between...

FWIW A Google search for [delphi locale site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=locale+site%3Astackoverflow.com) works just fine.

Comment: I found both [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276103/looking-for-question-containing-and) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275684/why-are-special-characters-ignored-in-search), both of which answer the question with slightly different search. Not sure if they're quite duplicates, but I'm still not 100% on how to call dups as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `[delphi] "locale"`. Words in double quotes are matched exactly. However, words in this case include punctuation, so this will miss occurrences of `locale,` or `locale.`.

A help summary for the search feature is available by clicking on “Advanced Search Tips” in the search result page. You can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search field to reach the search result page. A [more detailed help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) is available from the help center.

Alternatively, use a web search engine (e.g. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+-site:meta.stackoverflow.com+-site:chat.stackoverflow.com+delphi+%22locale%22)). For a tag name like `delphi`, that shouldn't result in many false positives.

[Edit by OP] BTW, this is documented (together with many handy notes) under the *Advanced search tips* in the top right of the search results screen.