# No search results found for "DELETE *" for a database-related question

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, search

I remember doing both a Stack and Google search for `DELETE *` in the not too distant past on a few occasions in regards to (MySQL) database-related questions where results were found.

I tried finding a duplicate for the following question that I saw this evening:

- [Proper PHP session garbage collection syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371470/proper-php-session-garbage-collection-syntax)

Yet, there were no results found which I find rather strange. I remember finding a few questions using the same syntax before, but not now.

I did use both [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags in my search as well as a deep Google search.

- Is the asterisk `*` an issue from within Stack's (search) architecture, and/or a bug?
- Are we/am I now reverted to vote the question as a typo instead?

---

Edit:

As per a comment left by a member ([approxiblue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/880772/approxiblue)), I used `code:"delete *" [mysql]` and it did find what I was looking for; a choice of questions to mark the question as a duplicate.

This is great, however I would like to know why I have to use that method now, rather than what I used to use, being just `delete *`.

---

Edit #2:

Upon clicking on "Advanced Search Tips" that shows additional search options (that drops down) and going through  https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching did not show the `code:` option, yet the "help/searching" contains `hascode:`. However that failed using `hascode: "delete *" [mysql]`. I did not find the `code:` option anywhere in that page or anywhere else on Stack.

- Is this an undocumented (search guru) feature?

Comment: You can search for code like this: [`code:"delete *"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3a%22delete%20*%22).

Comment: @approxiblue wowzers, nice. Thanks for the tip. It works yes, however and unfortunately, it does not answer my question as to why it used to work not so long ago when simply entering `DELETE *` which I don't get. Plus, this also seems to have an effect on how Google searches Stack which no longer seems to be the case here. I did a very deep Google search with no results as I could before. I feel something changed with Stack's architecture.

Comment: There is a known issue with searching for *special* characters within the search engine SE uses. Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275684/why-are-special-characters-ignored-in-search

Comment: @rene Thanks. I (originally) wanted to add in my question that I did in fact used quotes around it but didn't. That also failed me, in both Stack and Google which I remember using quite a few times within a 6-12 month period. I even tried escaping the asterisk `DELETE \*` and inside double quotes also.

Comment: @approxiblue Btw, upon clicking on "Advanced Search Tips" that shows additional searches and going through  http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching did not show the `code:` option, yet the "help/searching" contains `hascode:`. However that failed using `hascode: "delete *" [mysql]`. I did not find the `code:` yet, unless you know where that is documented.

Comment: The `code:` search option is marked [meta-tag:status-completed] [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55473), but [not officially documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/). `hascode` is worse, I haven't found any official acknowledgement, I learned about it [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331867).

Comment: @approxiblue Thanks for that, it was nice of you to do that. I did do an edit to my question earlier, in asking if this was an undocumented feature; well you answered that part ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: The `hascode` might not have worked because of the space between the colon and the quote. Note that the `code` example given doesn't have that. (I haven't tried it; this is a guess)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I tried a few variations, with and without spaces but alas, that didn't work. `code:"delete *"` is what worked as previously stated, but the reason is still unclear in regards to my original question.